# Multiple PCD files reading

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, lidar

I am using PCL library to process multiple PCD files. I don't understand how C++ works to read all the files in a directory. I tried many ways to do this and haven't got any results. Is there any example files or tutorials?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ***I don't understand how C++ works to read all the files in a directory.*** You will need to do that yourself. `c++` won't automatically read all files in a folder for you. If you have a compiler capable of using c++17 (the 2017 standard) and have that enabled you should be able to use the following code to iterate over your folder to find the names of the files: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.  I'm new in C++ . I got this error " fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
" while trying your link. I am using a linux machine. Is this a compiler issue?

Comment: You may need to pass `-std=c++17` as a command line argument to your compiler provided it supports the 2017 standard.